# RTSP for ipcamera in ios sdk

Tags: ios, video-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I am working on 1project start up.
And i want to do the following this.
1)Detect the camera by wifi and cameraid.
2)After detecting the camera.Fetch the stream from the camera to the phone
3)play that stream into the player.

Now i had done google and found that by RTSP we can achieve the following this.
But i am not sure or dont have the code to detect the camera from the camera id or by wifi and the detect the stream from that.
Can anyone guide me in this with the some sample source code.

Comment: depends on the camera really, some camera's publish themselves to the network using dms-sd , more commonly know by the apple variant Bonjour. for such camera's what you ask is fairly easy. any other would require scanning the network for a particular mac address, this used to be useful but apple has for the last year or so rejected apps that do that type of network scanning. so I guess do it at your own risk

Comment: to clarify that a bit , apple says that the wifi api's are private, I guess if you could find a non private api to do the scanning say from the server side, it would be ok.